# Reshaping array to fit in Keras model

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have some data with this shape:

```
X=np.array(X[0:10368]).reshape(432,24,1)
Y=np.array(Y[0:10368]).reshape(432,24,1)
```

So I want to feed my model this way:

```
X vector:           Y vector:         Example:

[24 x 1] vector --> [2x1] vector  / [0,1,...,24] ---> [0,1]
[24 x 1] vector --> [2x1] vector  / [0,1,...,24] ---> [0,0]
[24 x 1] vector --> [2x1] vector  / [0,1,...,24] ---> [1,0]
    .                 .                      .
    .                 .                      .
    .                 .                      .
432 batches         432 batches             432 batches
```

How can I reshape my Y to be this way?

```
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=(432, 2))
```

I want my Y to be: (432, 2)

Comment: What shape do your original labels have?

Comment: My original Y has this shape: (5192, 2). See my edit to see a more clear picture

Comment: So you only want to use 432 of your available 5192 label data? Why?

Comment: For every batch of 24 points in my X, I'll pass two points. 432 batches for Y and for X. See the estructure above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information that I have, I would suggest trying something like this:

```py
X = np.random.random(size=(5192, 24))
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=(5192, 2))

N = 432

indices = np.random.choice(X.shape[0], N, replace=False)
X_reduced = X[indices]
Y_reduced = Y[indices]

print(X_reduced.shape)
print(Y_reduced.shape)

#(432, 24)
#(432, 2)
```

Since your dataset is made up of `5192` entries, what I am doing is randomly choosing `432` indices from `X` and `Y` in order to get the shapes `(432, 24)` and `(432, 2)`. If you want to preserve the order of your data, you can just apply sliding windows of size `432` to your data without any randomness:

```py
X = np.random.random(size=(5192, 24))
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=(5192, 2))

N = 432

X = [X[i:i+N,:] for i in range(0, X.shape[0], N)]
Y = [Y[i:i+N,:] for i in range(0, Y.shape[0], N)]

print(X[0].shape)
print(Y[0].shape)

#(432, 24)
#(432, 2)
```

Note that the last batch has the shape `(8, 24)` for `X` and `(8,2)` for `Y` as the `5192` entries cannot be equally divided by `432`. You could, for example, copy the first `424` entries from your first batch into your last batch. That way all batches are equal.

Comment: But I would not like to mix my labels :( I want to preserve order in my Y

Comment: Updated answer.